# webdriver-manager start --detach do not detach the server in Azure DevOps

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, npm, azure-devops

I want to run my selenium tests in Azure DevOps. We use agents on ubuntu-20.04.

To achieve this I use npm. So my package.json has next scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "update_webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
  "start": "webdriver-manager start --detach",
  "test": "jest"
},
```

Then I have azure-pipelines.yml with next stage:

```
- stage: Test
displayName: Run tests
jobs:
  - job: Test
    steps:
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: npm install
      inputs:
        command: 'install'
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: npm update
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        customCommand: 'run update_webdriver'
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: npm start
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        customCommand: 'start'
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: npm test
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        customCommand: 'test'
```

Problem is that pipeline hangs on "npm start" command and doesn't go further. But locally --detach argument works fine.

Comment: Do you have a `seleniumAddress: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` in your `conf.js` file? If so, then comment it, and it would start automatically without needing the `--detach` argument.

Comment: This adress is default and works well locally. --detach argument also works locally, but not in CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I found is to run stanalone selenium in docker container.